# Is there a limit to the percentage of profits per year in a business for an H1B visa holder?

Tags: h1-visa

Can an H1B visa holder start a business and get profits? How much can he get per year? He is a totally passive investor in a joint-venture program. Is there any limit to the profits he can get every year?